# Deleting a certain line on linux

Tags: linux, sed

For example I have a `caf.txt` file and I want to delete a "donut" word in the document without entering the document on linux .How can I do it?

Comment: You want to delete just the word or the line containing that word?

Comment: line containing that word

Comment: Then check Mike's answer and accept it so the question could be closed. Thanks

Comment: It took less than a minute to find a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete just the word "donut"

```
sed -i 's/donut//g' caf.txt
```

To delete lines that contain the word "donut"

```
sed -i '/donut/d' caf.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is:

sed '/text_to_delete/d' filename | sponge filename

This will make the change to the source file.